# How to give permission to certain users to start Activity on Parse user type property?

Tags: android, permissions, parse-platform

assume that i have two types of users: students and instructors.

```html
ObjectID    UserName   Password    Type
-------     --------   --------   ------
8uJ03j7     user#1      ***        student
2835ruJ     user#2      ***        instructor
2835JhL     user#3      ***        student
```

Every time a user enter username and password and click log in i want to check their Type.
For example if user is student to Start new intent and open activity for student , same thing for Instructor.

I know how to make intent just need to check their type .

Answer (score 0):

After the login button click you can add Extras bundle to Intent.

In "`onResume`" you can extract the extras and read parameters form there.

Comment: But before i start intent i need to check users type.Example if(userType == "instructor") Intent intent = new Intent(for instructor class) and if (userType == "student") Intent intent = new Intent ( for student class) .. So just i need to figure out how to check that userType on Parse

Comment: if you are using Parse you just have to use the synchronised ParseUser.login and it will return with the relevant user object. Inside you will have the type. Don't forget to add a progress or something since is synchronised so the user will understand that something is happening.

Answer (score 0):

After the user has been logged in successfully query the user's data in background and extract the data you want. After getting the value simply start the intent.